# is it possible to sum up the properties of an array of objects and to filter it according to another property?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, chart.js, destructuring

My Title seems a bit confusing,

Here's my problem, i want to destructure an array of objects in order to use it's properties in a chartJS Line Graph.

Here's a reproduced array:

```
[{
    "page": "Page 1",
    "date": "2021-10-05",
    "visitors": 10
}, {
    "page": "Page 2",
    "date": "2021-10-05",
    "visitors": 20
}, {
    "page": "Page 3",
    "date": "2021-10-05",
    "visitors": 30
},{
    "page": "Page 1",
    "date": "2021-10-04",
    "visitors": 40
}, {
    "page": "Page 2",
    "date": "2021-10-04",
    "visitors": 50
}, {
    "page": "Page 3",
    "date": "2021-10-04",
    "visitors": 60
}]
```

Every entry contains a date ***(date)***, a visitors number ***(visitors)*** and a page name ***(page)***

For example, if a have 2 dates and 3 pages for whom i want to retrieve the numbers of visitors per date per page. My array returns 6 entries (3 pages for each date) ***the example above***.

So how can get the the number of visits of every page and get one array containing page names & dates **only once** & the related visits number like:

```
[   {
        page: pageName,
        dates: [],
        numberOfVisits: [],
    },
    {
        page: pageName,
        dates: [],
        numberOfVisits: [],
    },
    {
        page: pageName,
        dates: [],
        numberOfVisits: []
    },
]
```

i tried reducing the array and filtering it according to either the dates or the page names like so:

```
myArray.reduce((a, c) => {
    /* Filtering by date but this returns only one page name */
    let filtered = a.filter(el => (el.date === c.date));

    /* OR Filtering by page name but this returns only oneDate for each */
    /* let filtered = a.filter(el => (el.page === c.page)); */

    if (filtered.length > 0) {
        /* summing up the number of visits => this works in both cases */
        a[a.indexOf(filtered[0])].m_unique_visitors += +c.m_unique_visitors;

    } else {
        a.push(c);
    }
})
return a;
```

Comment: Can you provide an array data with as a minimal reproducible example and not a photo?

Comment: Oh yeah okay, gonna edit the post

Comment: Please also provide a clear example of desired _output_.

Comment: i just edited it !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest using `Array.reduce()` to group dates and visitors by page.

We'd sort the input array to ensure our output is also sorted by date.

The accumulator (acc) will have a property for each page, with a page name, a list of dates and number of visits array.

We'd use `Object.values()` to get the final array required.

```js
const a = [{ "page": "Page 1", "date": "2021-10-05", "visitors": 10 }, { "page": "Page 2", "date": "2021-10-05", "visitors": 20 }, { "page": "Page 3", "date": "2021-10-05", "visitors": 30 },{ "page": "Page 1", "date": "2021-10-04", "visitors": 40 }, { "page": "Page 2", "date": "2021-10-04", "visitors": 50 }, { "page": "Page 3", "date": "2021-10-04", "visitors": 60 }]

const sortByDate = ({ date: a}, { date:b }) => Date.parse(a) - Date.parse(b);

const result = Object.values(a.sort(sortByDate).reduce((acc, { page, date, visitors}) => { 
    acc[page] = acc[page] || { page, dates: [], numberOfVisits: []};
    acc[page].dates.push(date);
    acc[page].numberOfVisits.push(visitors);
    return acc;
}, {}))

console.log('Result:', result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

You could also structure the output slightly differently, to have a `visits` array, each element having a `date` and `visitors` value.

```js
const a = [{ "page": "Page 1", "date": "2021-10-05", "visitors": 10 }, { "page": "Page 2", "date": "2021-10-05", "visitors": 20 }, { "page": "Page 3", "date": "2021-10-05", "visitors": 30 },{ "page": "Page 1", "date": "2021-10-04", "visitors": 40 }, { "page": "Page 2", "date": "2021-10-04", "visitors": 50 }, { "page": "Page 3", "date": "2021-10-04", "visitors": 60 }]
   
const sortByDate = ({ date: a}, { date:b }) => Date.parse(a) - Date.parse(b);

const result = Object.values(a.sort(sortByDate).reduce((acc, { page, date, visitors}) => { 
    acc[page] = acc[page] || { page, visits: [] };
    acc[page].visits.push( { date, visitors});
    return acc;
}, {}));

console.log('Result:', result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you very much Terry ! This solution worked pretty good for me :) Great explanations also !

Comment: Great, glad to be of help, happy coding!